# Pass on syntactic sugar (or special method call) to attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, attributes

I have a class that, among other things, stores and manipulates `np.ndarray` data, saved in its `data` attribute.

```
class DataContainer:
    def __init__(self, data, ...):
        self.data = data
        # ...
```

Is it possible to pass on the syntactic sugar of, e.g. `a + b` leading to a call of `a.__add__(b)` to the `data` attribute in a programmatic way?

Of course I could just have a lot of methods like:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.data.__add__(other)
```

But with the long list of [special method names](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html#acts-like-number) supported by `np.ndarray`, I would be interested in:

1. Is there a more elegant way than explicitly defining a new method for each special method that I would like to forward?
2. Should this be done or would it be preferred to have it defined explicitly? (I am thinking, e.g. of possible issues with documentation parsers, ...?)

Note that I see inheritance from `np.ndarray` not as a feasible option, as this would overcomplicate the class. I merely intend to make working with the data a bit simpler by supporting some special methods ...

Comment: If you don't want to subclass and you don't want to forward the methods yourself, this could be tricky.

Comment: I could implement `__getattr__` myself and forward certain, pre-defined attribute names... I guess? But I was somewhat hoping for a nicer way...